# SwiftUI Text being truncated unexpectedly

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an HStack with three elements, as such:

```
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
    Text(title.uppercased())
        .lineLimit(1)
    Rectangle()
        .frame(height: 1)
        .foregroundColor(Color(.tertiaryLabel))
    Text(value)
        .lineLimit(1)
}
```

The first text element is being truncated in favor of the rectangle, which seems odd to me since the rectangle seems like it should compress as much as needed to accommodate the surrounding text.

[image: Demo]

I found that adding `.fixedSize()` to my Text objects fixes this issue, but is that the best/proper solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you look for `layoutPriority` modifier, like

```
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
    Text(title.uppercased())
        .lineLimit(1)
        .layoutPriority(1)        // << here !!
    Rectangle()
        .frame(height: 1)
        .foregroundColor(Color(.tertiaryLabel))
    Text(value)
        .lineLimit(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Coming from UIKit, I was looking for a concept like compression resistance, but didn't see the layoutPriority option.